# Debugging rails on passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, passenger

I am running a Rails 5 API on passenger locally. 
I start the server with `passenger start` command. 
I installed both `byebug` and `pry-rails` but none of them are working for me. 
I put a debug point, either with `byebug` or `binding.pry`, and when the code hits that point it does print the debug point in the server logs, with the code that it is executing but it doesn't actually stop, and I can type but I don't see the results of what I type.

I am starting to believe, based on posts like this one:
https://coderwall.com/p/rtskuw/create-break-points-in-rails-with-passenger-phusion-pry-pry-remote
that I can't actually debug like I debugged on `rails s` with passenger, but I don't actually want to believe that. There must be an easy way for me to debug the rails code on my passenger terminal without having to open a different terminal to act as a remote client or something like that.

Thank you very much